# Highlight cell border color when click, change back when click to others

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the code below:

```js
function highlight(cell){
  cell.style.borderColor = "red";
 }
 
 function originalColor(cell){
  cell.style.borderColor = "black";
 }
```

```css
td{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr>
 <td  onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 1</td>
 <td  onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 2</td>
 <td  onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td  onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 4</td>
 <td  onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 5</td>
 <td  onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 7</td>
 <td onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 8</td>
 <td onmousedown="highlight(this);" onblur="originalColor(this);">Cell 9</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

It will highlight the border to red when click, when click to the other cell, it suppose change back to black color, but it doesn't work, I try `onmouseup`, `onmouseover`, it doesn't work as what I want.

The technique I'hv tried is using `tabindex`, it works; but that can highlight one cell, if I try to select 2 cells at the same time, it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    var redNow = 1;
    function highlight(cell) {
        redNow == 1 ? redNow = 0 : redNow.style.borderColor = "black";
        redNow = cell;
        cell.style.borderColor = "red";
    }
    td {
      cursor: pointer;
     }
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 1</td>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 2</td>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 4</td>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 5</td>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 7</td>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 8</td>
        <td onmousedown="highlight(this);">Cell 9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

After your clarifying comment, if I understand correctly, you want to highlight a cell when you click it, and remove the highlighting if you choose to by clicking another element. If not, please clarify again. If that's indeed the case though, then the following code will work by traversing up the DOM to the parent table, then iterating through all the cells and taking appropriate action:

```js
function toggleBorderColor(c) {
    cells = c.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i in cells) {
       var cell = cells.item(i);
       cell.style.borderColor = (cell != c) ? "" : "red";
    }
}
```

```css
td {
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
 <td  onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 1</td>
 <td  onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 2</td>
 <td  onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td  onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 4</td>
 <td  onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 5</td>
 <td  onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 7</td>
 <td onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 8</td>
 <td onmousedown="toggleBorderColor(this);">Cell 9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. That is not what I want, what I mean is, when I click to Cell1, it will be highlighted, when I click to Cell2, Cell1 will back to back color and Cell2 will be highlighted...

Comment: You're welcome @helloworld1234. I've updated my answer, and I hope that it matches what you were looking for.