# How to unhighlight onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight

I have a problem regarding with highlight and unhighlight tables!
I have a table and when I click a td it highlights but when I click another it is also highlighted but my first click (which is highlighted) doesn't disappear.

this is my php:

```
<table class="cg-nav-wrapper cg-nav-wrapper-row-2" id="tableID" data-role="cg-nav-wrapper">
<tr>
        <?php
            include 'includes/connection/dbh.inc.php';

            $categories =array("Agriculture & Food", "Apparel, Textiles & Accessories", "Maintenance & Repair", "Auto & Transportation", "Business & Commercial", "Computer Electronics", "Electronics & Electrical Equipment", "Health & Beauty", "Home, Lights & Construction", "House Cleaning", "House Improvement", "Machinery, Industrial Parts & Tools", "Packaging, Advertising & Office");

                        $len = count($categories);


                        for($x = 0; $x < $len; $x++) {

                            $current = $categories[$x];

                            $sql = "SELECT count(company_business_category) AS total FROM businesses WHERE company_business_category ='$current' ";

                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                            $count=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

                            $num = $count['total'];

                            if($current=='Agriculture & Food'){
                                if($num>0){
                                    ?>
                            <td class="anchor-wrap anchor1-wrap" data-role="anchor1">
                                     <a class="anchor1 anchor-agricuture showSingle click-here agricutureTD" inputtype="checkbox" target="1" data-role="cont" >
                                      <i class="cg-icon"></i>
                                      <span class="desc">
                                         Agriculture &amp; Food
                                      </span>
                                     </a>
                              </td>

                        <?php
                    }else{
            ?>
                        <td class="anchor-wrap anchor1-wrap" data-role="anchor1">
                        <a class="anchor1 anchor-agricuture click-here agricutureTD"
                                    data-role="cont" >
                                                <i class="cg-icon"></i>
                                                <span class="desc">
                                                    Agriculture &amp; Food
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                            else if($current=='Apparel, Textiles & Accessories'){
                                if($num>0){
                                    ?>
                                        <td class="anchor-wrap anchor2-wrap showSingle apparelTD " target="2" data-role="anchor2">
                                            <a class="anchor2 anchor-apparel click-here apparelTD"  data-role="cont" >
                                                <i class="cg-icon"></i>
                                                <span class="desc">
                                                    Apparel,Textiles &amp; Accessories
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    <?php
                                }else{
                                    ?>
                                        <td class="anchor-wrap anchor2-wrap cl apparelTD" target="2" data-role="anchor2">
                                         <a class="anchor2 anchor-apparel click-here apparelTD"  data-role="cont">
                                                <i class="cg-icon"></i>
                                                <span class="desc">
                                                    Apparel,Textiles &amp; Accessories
                                                </span>
                                            </a>
                                        </td>
                                    <?php
                                }
                            }

                         }
                    ?>

        </table>  ....
```

this is my js:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var target = $('.cg-main').html();
    var nothing = '<div class="item util-clearfix targetDiv" data-spm="1" id="div1">' +
                            '<h3 class="big-title anchor1'+
                                        '404 Nothing Found' +
                            '</h3>'+
                            '<div class="sub-item-wrapper util-clearfix">'+
                                    '<div class="sub-item">'+       
                                        ''+                                 
                                    '</div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'; 

                    $('.click-here').on('click',function(){

                      var $td = $(this).parent();
                        $('.click-here').not(this).removeClass("selected");
                        $td.toggleClass("selected");
                    });
                });
```

How do I un-highlight my previous click? Someone help me T.T im stuck here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252350/highlight-cell-border-color-when-click-change-back-when-click-to-others Try to check here

Comment: That's not an answer by jQuery. This isn't duplicate in my opinion

Comment: @TerryWei hi! thank you for responding, but it doesn't work. Do you have any other alternatives?

Comment: @PGCodeRider I've already tried this but it's still the same

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: That's my fault not check the answer. Edited answer's given. This is the jQuery selector's problem. You'd better know what you're selecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's problem here:

```
$('.click-here').on('click', function() {

    var $td = $(this).parent();
    $('.click-here').not(this).removeClass("selected");
    $td.toggleClass("selected");
});
```

the `selected` is for `click-here`'s parent.

so

`$('.click-here').not(this).removeClass("selected");`

should be

`$('.selected').not($td).removeClass("selected");`

**Edited**

My wrong for not replaced the `click-here` to `.selected`

Comment: It still won't work everything is still highlighted when i click another td

Comment: Do `$('.selected').not($td)` select the highlighted element?

Comment: Yeay! It's working!!! thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Would you please check this as answer if this helps?

Comment: Done! thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: That's my pleasure and thanks!